# как правильно написать post запрос на сервер?

Tags: android, http, post, wsdl

есть определенный код, который отправляет запрос на сервер. попробовал его протестировать в программе SOAPUI работает,  пробую через приложение достучаться к серверу, ответ не приходит.

```
private String login(String username, String password) {

    String xml = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://ololo");
        httppost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        httppost.setHeader("Host", "oooo");
        httppost.setHeader("Expect", "100-continue");
        httppost.setHeader("SOAPAction", "http://ololo");

        String str = "<soapenv:Envelope \n" +
                "xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" \n" +
                "xmlns:mob=\"http://ololo">\n" +
                "   <soapenv:Header/>\n" +
                "   <soapenv:Body>\n" +
                "      <mob:Auth>\n" +
                "         <!--Optional:-->\n" +
                "         <mob:authRequisites>\n" +
                "            <!--Optional:-->\n" +
                "            <mob:Login>" + username + "</mob:Login>\n" +
                "            <!--Optional:-->\n" +
                "            <mob:Password>" + password + "</mob:Password>\n" +
                "         </mob:authRequisites>\n" +
                "      </mob:Auth>\n" +
                "   </soapenv:Body>\n" +
                "</soapenv:Envelope>";

        httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(str));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()/*,"UTF-8"*/);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return xml;
}
```

ответ:

```
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <AuthResponse xmlns="http://ololo">
         <AuthResult>
            <ErrorCode>xxx</ErrorCode>
            <SessionID>00000000000000</SessionID>
         </AuthResult>
      </AuthResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

пример запроса через SOAPUI :

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mob="http://ololo">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mob:Auth>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mob:authRequisites>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <mob:Login>xxx</mob:Login>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <mob:Password>xxx</mob:Password>
         </mob:authRequisites>
      </mob:Auth>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

проверил статус:

```
     String status = String.valueOf(response.getStatusLine()); 
в логах ответ такой: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Comment: А пример ответа можешь привести? И откуда код появился, может лучше переделать все на каком-нибудь ksoap2-android?

Comment: @jangorussia, ответ привел. структуру запроса дали, про ksoap2-android не слышал..

Comment: У меня выходят гадания на кофейно гуще. Проверь SoapAction(заголовок) - может значение неверное, ContentType  поменять попробуй на application/soap+xml. либа с помощью которой я работаю вот: http://simpligility.github.io/ksoap2-android/index.html

Comment: @jangorussia  да я вообще не пойму тоже, так как до недавнего времени все работало, потом на сервере переделали  логику, и начались проблемы. через SOAPUI когда пробовал там вообще без заголовков просто запрос отправлял, единственное подкладывал wsdl. просто мне надо понять, может ответ от сервера идет в не верной кодировке? или это с моей стороны проблема?

Comment: Ну про кодировку заголовки ответа посмотри. С SOAPUI не работал - каких-то тонкостей не знаю. Судя по тому что ты рассказываешь косяк не с твой стороны, раз до этого работало. Судя по всему он не авторизуется - а когда работало, ты тестировал ситуации если не проходила авторизация?

Comment: Стоит сравнить заголовки с SOAPUI & Android устройства. Похоже что какой-то из заголовков отсутствует для коректной работы. У меня был вариант, что пришлось кодировать base64

Comment: @Сергей да, телефон не может достучаться до сервера по ссылке, которая в коде

Comment: @xAqweRx  в SOAPUI я подкладывал сам wsdl, а телефону тоже получается его нужно указать? или не обязательно?

Comment: c SOAP не работал, потому могу только посоветовать разобраться с тем что посоветовал @jangorussia (ksoap2). По поводу самого POST запроса, то он оформлен правильно. И вероятнее всего там не хватает wsdl

Comment: адресс сервера начинается не на `http://127.0.0.1` случайно?

Comment: @metalurgus нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код для SOAP запроса с использованием KSOAP взятый [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34156613/2685996)

```
String SOAP_ACTION = "YOUR_ACTION_NAME";
String METHOD_NAME = "YOUR_METHOD_NAME";
String NAMESPACE = "YOUR_NAME_SPACE";
String URL = "YOUR_URL";
SoapPrimitive resultString = null;

try {
    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    addPropertyForSOAP(Request);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
    resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

    Log.i("SOAP Result", "Result Celsius: " + resultString);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e("SOAP Result", "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
}
if(resultString != null) {
    return resultString.toString();
}
else{
    return "error";
}
```